# return a vector from a function that accepts a scalar

Tags: r, function, vector, dplyr

I have:

```
df <- tibble(
  col1 = c(1, -2, 1000, 100),
  row_number = seq_along(col1)
)
```

I want to take a log of the first column with the following function:

```
trycatch_log <- function( column ) {
  tryCatch( print( log(column) ),
            condition = function(w) print(NA))
}
```

but: `trycatch_log(df$col1)` returns `NA`

When I run the loop:

```
for ( i in df$col1){
  trycatch_log((i))
}
```

I get the desired outputs, but as individual scalars, and not a vector

```
[1] 0
[1] NA
[1] 6.907755
[1] 4.60517
```

How can I pass the column and return a new column showing the values desired

Comment: Your function is `print`ing

Comment: results in same error

Comment: `print` doesn't return value.  It just prints on the console.  I am not sure why you are wrapping with `print` and then needed the return value.  WIth your current function you can wrap with `Vectorize` to return the print i.e. `Vectorize(trycatch_log)(df$col1)`

Comment: that worked, thanks

Comment: Is this your real use case? Why not just use `function(x) {x[x <= 0] <- NA; log(x)}`?